# Launch Windows process as another user without directly knowing the password

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, encryption

We have a machine that basically runs as a local system in kiosk mode by auto-logging in as a local machine user.

The user needs to launch a program that runs in a domain account.  What we've done in the past is to encrypt the domain, user and password details in a file.  Then decrypt them to launch the program  (C# Process.Start).  This program needs a domain account to use Windows authentication for accessing a SQLServer database.

However this is a security hole, the decryption password is inside the launcher program so someone could inspect the code and get access to a domain account.

Also, we cannot require the users to type in the account details, the users don't know these details, it's a one user for all type of account.

One thought is maybe there's a way to store an access token that I could use to launch the domain program.  At least in that scenario the access token wouldn't have the clear text of the password.  I looked at Windows Credential Manager but that seems mainly to be used for web sites and wants to store details as text.

Another option I'm investigating is a Windows service.  The service would run in a third account and would hold the "secrets".  However, I'm not sure how I would launch a process for the kiosk user and have it work properly with the user desktop / UI.

Comment: Please change question title: in your scenario, you are "directly knowing" the password", and want it stored somehow so you can use it to start a new process.
If I'm not wrong, you are asking "what is the best way to securely store credentials and use them in my software?"

Comment: Generate and install a certificate in the (local) users certificate store, use that to encrypt and decrypt the domain credentials files

Comment: Wouldn't using a certificate have the same issue as before?  Someone could run their own program to decrypt and get clear text details.

Comment: Why does the program *have* to be run as the domain user?  (If there is a good reason, it will almost certainly mean that you must have the password.)

Comment: U want to increase the security of your kiosk system. But it's not clear how much u want to increase. Or better stated, your threat model (TM) is not clear. If u don't already have a thread model, then I suggest creating one. MS has a lot of info on their site about threat modeling. With TM u can make decisions about what kind of additional protection against reverse engineering to put in place. The methods u mention rely on obscurity (as opposed to stronger methods of "what you have", "what you know", and "what you are"). Deciding how long u let an attack go on can determine the method to use

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/7620/windows-run-as-without-knowing-the-password